# Alfresco: Fetching data from cmis response

Tags: php, xml, alfresco, alfresco-share

My intention is to basically list the folders in Alfresco site using php script, to achieve this I execute curl statement in terminal as below,

```
curl -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/children
```

and I get the response as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:alf="http://www.alfresco.org" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<author><name>admin</name></author>
<generator version="4.2.0 (4576)">Alfresco (Community)</generator>
<icon>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/images/logo/AlfrescoLogo16.ico</icon>
<id>urn:uuid:02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2-children</id>
<link rel="service" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis"/>
<link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/children"/>
<link rel="via" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2"/>
<link rel="up" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/4046a051-6cde-4049-a222-53365ac4fbd4/children" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="down" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/descendants" type="application/cmistree+xml"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/foldertree" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/tree" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="first" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/children?pageNo=1&amp;pageSize=-1&amp;guest=&amp;format=atomfeed" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="last" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2/children?pageNo=1&amp;pageSize=-1&amp;guest=&amp;format=atomfeed" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<title>mysite Children</title>
<updated>2013-12-11T17:11:32.963+05:30</updated>
<opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>-1</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
<cmisra:numItems>1</cmisra:numItems>
<entry>
<author><name>admin</name></author>
<content src="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/content"/><id>urn:uuid:863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f</id>
<link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f"/>
<link rel="edit" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/allowableactions"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/rels"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/pols"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/acl"/>
<link rel="up" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry"/>
<link rel="down" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/children" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="down" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/descendants" type="application/cmistree+xml"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/foldertree" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f/tree" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="describedby" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/type/cmis:folder"/>
<link rel="service" href="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis"/>
<published>2013-12-11T17:11:32.522+05:30</published>
<summary>Document Library</summary>
<title>documentLibrary</title>
<updated>2013-12-13T11:50:55.893+05:30</updated>
<app:edited>2013-12-13T11:50:55.893+05:30</app:edited>
<alf:icon>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/images/icons/space-icon-default-16.gif</alf:icon>
<cmisra:object>
<cmis:properties>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds" displayName="Allowed Child Object Types Ids" queryName="cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds"/>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId" displayName="Object Type Id" queryName="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:folder</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:path" displayName="Path" queryName="cmis:path"><cmis:value>/Sites/mysite/documentLibrary</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name" displayName="Name" queryName="cmis:name"><cmis:value>documentLibrary</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="cmis:creationDate" displayName="Creation Date" queryName="cmis:creationDate"><cmis:value>2013-12-11T17:11:32.522+05:30</cmis:value></cmis:propertyDateTime>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:changeToken" displayName="Change token" queryName="cmis:changeToken"/>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModifiedBy" displayName="Last Modified By" queryName="cmis:lastModifiedBy"><cmis:value>admin</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:createdBy" displayName="Created by" queryName="cmis:createdBy"><cmis:value>admin</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId" displayName="Object Id" queryName="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/863dba18-b564-4042-b9a9-e26d83eee13f</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="alfcmis:nodeRef" displayName="Alfresco Node Ref" queryName="alfcmis:nodeRef"/>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId" displayName="Base Type Id" queryName="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:folder</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId>
<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:parentId" displayName="Parent Id" queryName="cmis:parentId"><cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/02f9530f-a1b1-4d6d-b479-b5355692b8e2</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId>
<cmis:propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModificationDate" displayName="Last Modified Date" queryName="cmis:lastModificationDate"><cmis:value>2013-12-13T11:50:55.893+05:30</cmis:value></cmis:propertyDateTime>
<alf:aspects>
<alf:appliedAspects>P:sys:localized</alf:appliedAspects>
<alf:appliedAspects>P:cm:titled</alf:appliedAspects>
<alf:appliedAspects>P:cm:ownable</alf:appliedAspects>
<alf:appliedAspects>P:cm:tagscope</alf:appliedAspects>
<alf:appliedAspects>P:st:siteContainer</alf:appliedAspects>
<alf:properties>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cm:description" displayName="Description" queryName="cm:description"><cmis:value>Document Library</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cm:title" displayName="Title" queryName="cm:title"/>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cm:owner" displayName="Owner" queryName="cm:owner"><cmis:value>admin</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cm:tagScopeSummary" displayName="Tag Summary" queryName="cm:tagScopeSummary"/>
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="st:componentId" displayName="Component Id" queryName="st:componentId"><cmis:value>documentLibrary</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString>
</alf:properties>
</alf:aspects>
</cmis:properties>
</cmisra:object>
<cmisra:pathSegment>documentLibrary</cmisra:pathSegment>
</entry>
```

How do i fetch the child data in php? i.e basically the title 'documentLibrary' and it's objectId.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the Atom feeds on your own, you can use the following PHP-library: http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is as simple as what you have described, you can use XPath in PHP to query the data you're after.

Here are the XPath queries you could use:

**Select the "Title" element (I recommend selecting propertyString cmis:name instead - although the CMIS spec specifies that cmis:name must be set in the atom:title element, I've found cases where the repository does not set the title element as it defined in the CMIS specification)**

```
//cmis:propertyString[contains(@propertyDefinitionId, 'cmis:name')][1]/cmis:value/text()
```

**Select cmis:objectId**

```
//cmis:propertyId[contains(@propertyDefinitionId, 'cmis:objectId')][1]/cmis:value[1]/text()
```

If you're interacting with Alfresco via CMIS for more complex use cases, look at the Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP Client (http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html) for a robust client library and see if the client library fits your needs.

Edit - A simple example to put it all together...

```
// Load the XML String into a SimpleXMLElement
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlResponse);

// Optional but good practice - register namespaces
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('cmis', 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/');

// Execute XPath Query
$result = $sxe->xpath("//cmis:propertyString[contains(@propertyDefinitionId, 'cmis:name')][1]/cmis:value/text()");

// Do something with the result.
echo $result[0]  // For XPath above this will print: "documentLibrary"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have no idea about cmis and it's processing. Please excuse me if am asking a non-sense question now. The response what I get after executing the curl command will be saved in a variable, say $response. How can I get the values from this variable.

Comment: Rumi, I've updated my answer based on your comment.  This update is just a simple example.  If you're doing anything more then what we're discussing, I highly recommend looking at the Apache Chemistry PHP Client library.